# Json Error when parsing as object rather than array :getJSONObject (java.lang.String) in JSONObject cannot be applied to (int)

Tags: android, json, google-maps, android-studio

My previous issue was that "org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray"

So I changed this JSONArray stationsJsonArray = newJSONArray(stationsJsonString); to this JSONObject stationsJsonObject = new JSONObject(stationsJsonString);

Based on the answer gave in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53397588/jsonexeption-when-parsing-local-json-file) where my first issue was resolved

Which fixed the initial issue however now I get this issue getJSONObject (java.lang.String) in JSONObject cannot be applied to (int). I'm aware that only string values can be passed into JSONObject but this used to be a JSONArray so how would I use and an array without causing the Json Exception thrown in the previous thread.

I've Honestly no idea how to fix this now. Any And All help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
private class AsyncTaskGetMareker extends AsyncTask<String , String, JSONObject> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String stationsJsonString = getJSONFromAssets();
            try {
                JSONObject stationsJsonObject = new JSONObject(stationsJsonString);
                return stationsJsonObject;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //This will only happen if an exception is thrown above:
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute (JSONObject result){
            if (result !=null){
                for (int i =0; i <result.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject= null;
                    try {
                        jsonObject= result.getJSONObject(i);
                        String name=jsonObject.getString("name");
                        String lat=jsonObject.getString("lat");
                        String lang=jsonObject.getString("lang");

                        drawMarker(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat),
                                Double.parseDouble(lang)), name);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        private void drawMarker(LatLng point, String name) {
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(point);
            markerOptions.snippet(name);
            mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        }
    }
```

And the Json File:

```
{
   "predictions" : [
      {
         "description" : "GAME Paisley, High Street, Paisley, UK",
         "id" : "d4fafbac99296d0a545170bb9af984e6251ac917",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 4,
               "offset" : 0
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJN0z6gTdJiEgREKQBicnWcAs",
         "reference" : "ChIJN0z6gTdJiEgREKQBicnWcAs",
         "structured_formatting" : {
            "main_text" : "GAME Paisley",
            "main_text_matched_substrings" : [
               {
                  "length" : 4,
                  "offset" : 0
               }
            ],
            "secondary_text" : "High Street, Paisley, UK"
         },
         "terms" : [
            {
               "offset" : 0,
               "value" : "GAME Paisley"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 14,
               "value" : "High Street"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 27,
               "value" : "Paisley"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 36,
               "value" : "UK"
            }
         ],
         "types" : [ "establishment" ]
      },
      {
         "description" : "GAME Glasgow Union Street, Union Street, Glasgow, UK",
         "id" : "9579c1d2df7575a2eb479ccd987cf29ab0ab9c6e",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 4,
               "offset" : 0
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJ2YlAjJ5GiEgRu7aBLOFlkkc",
         "reference" : "ChIJ2YlAjJ5GiEgRu7aBLOFlkkc",
         "structured_formatting" : {
            "main_text" : "GAME Glasgow Union Street",
            "main_text_matched_substrings" : [
               {
                  "length" : 4,
                  "offset" : 0
               }
            ],
            "secondary_text" : "Union Street, Glasgow, UK"
         },
         "terms" : [
            {
               "offset" : 0,
               "value" : "GAME Glasgow Union Street"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 27,
               "value" : "Union Street"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 41,
               "value" : "Glasgow"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 50,
               "value" : "UK"
            }
         ],
         "types" : [ "establishment" ]
      },
      {
         "description" : "Game, Saint Enoch Square, Glasgow, UK",
         "id" : "582edc64f3d6654d8ff9a8da364c37a8e0544102",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 4,
               "offset" : 0
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJq2yljp5GiEgRpsnAfUFKGEA",
         "reference" : "ChIJq2yljp5GiEgRpsnAfUFKGEA",
         "structured_formatting" : {
            "main_text" : "Game",
            "main_text_matched_substrings" : [
               {
                  "length" : 4,
                  "offset" : 0
               }
            ],
            "secondary_text" : "Saint Enoch Square, Glasgow, UK"
         },
         "terms" : [
            {
               "offset" : 0,
               "value" : "Game"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 6,
               "value" : "Saint Enoch Square"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 26,
               "value" : "Glasgow"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 35,
               "value" : "UK"
            }
         ],
         "types" : [ "establishment" ]
      },
      {
         "description" : "GAME Glasgow King's Inch Road, King's Inch Road, Glasgow, UK",
         "id" : "b60dbbc529f25226dfee4c05c80de8e92137588d",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 4,
               "offset" : 0
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJv2Te_ENPiEgRknxQydZhR8Q",
         "reference" : "ChIJv2Te_ENPiEgRknxQydZhR8Q",
         "structured_formatting" : {
            "main_text" : "GAME Glasgow King's Inch Road",
            "main_text_matched_substrings" : [
               {
                  "length" : 4,
                  "offset" : 0
               }
            ],
            "secondary_text" : "King's Inch Road, Glasgow, UK"
         },
         "terms" : [
            {
               "offset" : 0,
               "value" : "GAME Glasgow King's Inch Road"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 31,
               "value" : "King's Inch Road"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 49,
               "value" : "Glasgow"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 58,
               "value" : "UK"
            }
         ],
         "types" : [ "establishment" ]
      },
      {
         "description" : "GAME, Cowglen Road, Glasgow, UK",
         "id" : "86a4ed10b3b9b609f68533f1c47dc8f9ae5d2aee",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 4,
               "offset" : 0
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJT3vEiYRIiEgR4EIqP8jmL6o",
         "reference" : "ChIJT3vEiYRIiEgR4EIqP8jmL6o",
         "structured_formatting" : {
            "main_text" : "GAME",
            "main_text_matched_substrings" : [
               {
                  "length" : 4,
                  "offset" : 0
               }
            ],
            "secondary_text" : "Cowglen Road, Glasgow, UK"
         },
         "terms" : [
            {
               "offset" : 0,
               "value" : "GAME"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 6,
               "value" : "Cowglen Road"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 20,
               "value" : "Glasgow"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 29,
               "value" : "UK"
            }
         ],
         "types" : [ "establishment" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice:

```
    JsonObject getJsonObject(String name) //parameter type should be String

    for (int i =0; i <result.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject= null;
                        try {
                            jsonObject= result.getJSONObject(i);//but you pass an int
                            String name=jsonObject.getString("name");
```

Comment: I know but how do i do it with the JSONArray, withouth the JSONExeption shown in the thread i linked